# webpackでサーバー側のモジュールを無害化したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

browserifyであれば、ignoreに追加したモジュールは無害化され、require()は空の参照を返します。
webpackで同様のことをしたいと思い、以下のような`webpack.config.babel.js`の`external`を利用してビルドを行いましたが、htmlから読み込むと`ReferenceError: express is not defined`となってしまいます。

```bash
npm run build

# > webpack-external-trouble@ build /Users/59naga/Downloads/fuga
# > webpack

# Hash: 6a8e05a3b6e4983a8b39
# Version: webpack 1.12.2
# Time: 229ms
#         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
#     bundle.js  2.24 kB       0  [emitted]  main
# bundle.js.map  1.91 kB       0  [emitted]  main
#     + 2 hidden modules
```

`webpack.config.babel.js`

```js
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./index.js",

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  externals: [
    'express',
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },

  devtool: '#source-map',
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webpack-external-trouble",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.33",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "stage": 0
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
// Dependencies
import express from 'express'

// Publish as singleton
class Module{

}

export default new Module
```

[image: index.htmlから読み込んだbundle.js]

`bundle.js`を読み込んでも、`ReferenceError: express is not defined`を起こさないためには`webpack.config.babel.js`をどのように設定すればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1021
>   こちらに方法が載っていました。

`package.json`の`browser`フィールドに無害化したいモジュール名を入力し、`webpack.config.babel.js`の`externals`は削除することで、`bundle.js`をhtmlから読み込んでもエラーが発生しなくなりました。

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webpack-external-trouble",
  "private": true,
  "browser": {
    "express": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.33",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "stage": 0
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.babel.js`

```js
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./index.js",

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },

  devtool: '#source-map',
}
```

[image: htmlからbundle.jsを読み込む]